# how to hide some value in checkboxlist on databind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am loading a checkboxlist from database dynamically.

In database I have values like :

```
 Sun
 Mon
 Tue
 Wed
 Thu
 Fri
 Sat
```

Here is my checkbox List

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkDays" runat="server" CssClass="checkbox-inline"
  DataTextField="dayValue" DataValueField="dayId"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

But what I actually want here is to hide Tue, Thu, and Sat when I bind values to checkbox list and only thing which should be visible to user is Sun,Mon,Wed,Fri

I don't want to hide them using

```
chkDay.Items[itemPosition] = hide;
```

because order can be changed anytime in database.

Comment: Can you show code snippet when data binding occurred from code behind (also how the items are populated from DB? I don't think `chkDay.Items[itemPosition] = hide;` is a proper way to hide `ListItem` from `CheckBoxList` control.

Answer (score 0):

The better thing to do, is to put another bit column in your database to indicate if the row is `Enabled` or not. And then when you bind the checkbox list select the rows which are `Enabled = 1`